# State the range of each function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

> $f(x) = 4\cos(6x)$
>
> $f(x) = -2(x-3)^2+5$

For the first one I just graphed it and found $y = -4$ and $y = 4$

For the second one I also graphed it and found $y = 5$

Did I state the range correctly or must it be in some different format?

Comment: What you've found are the limits of the ranges of the two functions.  Now you just need to specify all the values $y$ could take.

Comment: @user3294068 so for the first one $-4 \le y \le 4$ and second one $y \le 5 $?

Comment: @free_mind Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without graph, note that, for $(1)$ we have:

$-1\le \cos \alpha  \le 1 \quad \forall \alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ , so:

$-4 \le \cos (6x) \le 4 \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.

For $(2)$ note that:
$(x-3)^2 \ge 0 \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R} $ so that $-2(x-3)^2 \le 0 \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R} $ and:

$5-2(x-3)^2\le 5 \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.